# How to set up gitconfig to open winmerge without validating each modified file?

Tags: git, config, winmerge

I've set up the gitconfig so that difftool uses winmerge to compare file but for each file the command prompt ask me if i want to launch winmerge.

git difftool
Viewing (1/7): ###1
Launch 'winmerge' [Y/n]? y

Viewing (2/7): ###2
Launch 'winmerge' [Y/n]? y
'###' being filenames

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The configuration setting `difftool.prompt` controls whether `git difftool` asks first. You can temporarily set it to false for one command with `git -c difftool.prompt=false <rest of command here>` or use `git config` to set it in your per-repository or global configuration to change the default for this repository or all repositories in which it is not specified.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me, if added 'prompt = false' to the diff config and i'm still being asked for each modified file if i want to open it

Comment: Check, after adding your setting, that it's "taken": run `git config --get difftool.prompt` from the command line. If it has not taken, you might want to run `git config --list --show-origin` to see what settings are being set in which config files.

Comment: Indeed, it was not taken. It works great, thanks.